# How to move li element slowly from bottom to top position when click on it with some animation effect

Tags: html, css

I have a list item and I want an effect that will slowly move from bottom to top  when a user clicks on any list items, like fly from bottom to top in slow motion. If possible, I am looking for a pure CSS solution.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<body>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <h2>List Header</h2>
    <p>An example of how to add a heading element inside the list item.</p>

    <ul class="w3-ul w3-border">
      <li>
        <h2>Item 1</h2>
      </li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script>
    $('li').on('click', function() {
      $(this).parent().prepend(this);
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Animating the reordering of a list would not be possible with CSS alone. However, it's [possible with React](https://github.com/joshwcomeau/react-flip-move).

Comment: You can try to adapt jQuery UI `.sortable()`/`.draggable()` to your situation.

Comment: I don't generally like to use jQuery UI, but it's (possibly) faster and easier than using React, especially if you have never used React before.